# Typescript, Multiple Parameters with JQuery.on

Tags: jquery, typescript

Using Typescript, I am having difficulty with an event.

The event raises like this...

```
$(this).trigger('customEvent', { page: index });
```

This has always worked fine in Javascript. But my wiring to this is not working in Typescript when I try to get the parameters...

```
$(someSelector).on('customEvent', (e, page) => {
   // do some stuff with page or e
});
```

It just refuses to let me have the two parameters. But the standard `e` does not contain all of the information I need for this to work right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is be cause of the signature defined for event handlers. All members after the first are optional see : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jquery/jquery.d.ts?source=c#L2280

Therefore make page optional (using `?`):

```
$(someSelector).on('customEvent', (e, page?) => {
   // do some stuff with page or e
});
```

Comment: THANK YOU. YOU ARE A GOD AMONG INSECTS

Comment: Thank you - definitely underrated answer